# Receipt Validation Server Help in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, server, in-app-purchase

I am currently making an iOS app that does an Auto Renewable Subscription. I am having trouble authenticating the receipt due to the server URL. I have implemented the code using sandbox. The test results were great. The only thing I need now is a server to take it to production instead of the test environment. I know the protocol for this is app -> server -> app store -> server -> app. I have put my app on firebase hoping to use their database as a server (My knowledge in servers is limited), but they don't have a URL to put. So my question is to see if there are any other easier options or how to make my authentication process work with firebase (I don't want to use firebase authentication, just the authentication recommended for the iOS app store).

Comment: I just found SwiftyStoreKit as a possible answer. Only question I have regarding to SwiftyStoreKit is will it be safe to run this in my app? I know apple likes the app to server to App Store process so I don't know if this would make my app unacceptable to the app store during its review.

Comment: Firebase doesn't have any server side validation available for in app purchases, you'll have to setup your own server to handle validation of the receipt otherwise it will be easy to bypass on jailbroken devices.

Comment: @AlexCatch is there any server you'd recommend?

Comment: I'd just spin up a simple node.js server on something like Heroku or AWS using a simple lib built for iap validation like https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase